How to decrypt SMIME encrypted outlook msg files in openssl using localstore certificates
I'm trying to figure out how to script such scenario:

I got outlook msg files (one msg in one file) encrypted using PKI certtificates
PKI certificates are stored in Cert:\CurrentUser\My\ - I got private keys (Windows OS)
I've tried:
PS> Unprotect-CmsMessage -path mail.msg -To 'thumprint_of_pki_certificate' but got error "no ecrypted data"
I got info that there is diference beetween encrypting/decripting using certificates and smime encryption.
so I tried to figure out with:

openssl smime -decrypt -in mail.msg -recip mycert.pem -inkey key.pem
this shoud work if I can use windows store (can't export private keys to get key.pem)...
Q: is a way to show to openssl windows local store?

When you say you can’t export the key, is it because you don’t know how?

You need to export the private key either in PEM format or as a pfx file. Then
openssl smime -decrypt -in mail.msg -recip recipient.pem

or, if you have a pfx file (which is PCKS#12 format), then first convert it to pem with
openssl pkcs12 -in recipient.pfx -out recipient.pem

Your question is a bit confusing. Does this answer it?

Thanks, but i don't have pfx or PKCS#12 file, private keys are in local windows store and I am not able to export them.
is there a way to point in openssl as "recipient.pem" something like thumprint in windows localstore ?

I don’t think so, but if that is what you are asking, perhaps you should edit your question to make that clearer.
